# How to use pd.IntervalIndex.is_overlapping to find overlapping Intervals in a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, intervals

Using the new Pandas `IntervalIndex.is_overlapping` you can check your IntervalIndex for overlapping. The function only Returns a Boolean Value for the whole DataFrame but does not Group/identify overlapping/not-overlapping intervals. How do you achieve this using the efficient Pandas Interval functionality?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 1),(1, 2),(3,5),(2,7),(5,12),(1,9)],closed='both')
print(df.is_overlapping())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `overlaps`

```
[df.overlaps(x)for x in df]
Out[344]: 
[array([ True,  True, False, False, False,  True]),
 array([ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True]),
 array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True]),
 array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]),
 array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True]),
 array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])]
```